# NSString decode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I send HEAD request with this code to get only the headers:

```
NSURL *url = [[webview request] URL];

NSMutableURLRequest *re = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[re setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:re delegate:self];
```

And in the response, i get with this the headers :

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSDictionary *f = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSString *content_Disposition = [f valueForKey:@"Content-Disposition"];
}
```

The problem is that if i log the `NSDictionary` i get this as the `ontent-Disposition`:

```
"Content-Disposition" = "attachment; filename=\"\U00e3\U00e5\U00e3\U00e5 \U00e8\U00f1\U00e4-\U00e0\U00e9\U00e6\U00e4 \U00e9\U00e5\U00ed.mp3\"";
```

but in the `NSString *content_Disposition` i get :

```
attachment; filename="ãåãå èñä-àéæä éåí.mp3"
```

How i can convert it to be the good string and not what i get?

Comment: It seems like it is unicoded character. Try to convert to unicode string.

Comment: Try using NSString stringWithUTF8String api..

Comment: Convert it to NSData and initWithData:encoding: and then use NSUnicodeStringEncoding and the encoding option.

Comment: @insane-36 it's not working

Comment: The filenames are the same. It's just NSLog that displays them differently.

Comment: So it's possible to decode it? because if i download the file from FireFox it's give me the real name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSDictionary *f = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSString *content_Disposition = [f valueForKey:@"Content-Disposition"];
    char cString[] = content_Disposition;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
    NSString *content_Formatted = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"content formatted: %@", content_Formatted);
}
```

UPDATE

For getting the file name you can do something like this:

```
NSString *content_Disposition = [f valueForKey:@"Content-Disposition"];

NSRange rangeInit = [content_Disposition rangeOfString:@"filename="];

if (rangeInit.location != NSNotFound && rangeInit.length != NSNotFound) {
    int fileNameInit = rangeInit.location + rangeInit.length;
    NSRange rangeEnd = [content_Disposition rangeOfString:@" " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(fileNameInit, [content_Disposition length] - fileNameInit)];
    int fileNameLength = 0;

    if (rangeEnd.location != NSNotFound && rangeEnd.length != NSNotFound) {
        fileNameLength = rangeEnd.location - fileNameInit;
    } else {
        fileNameLength = [content_Disposition length] - fileNameInit;
    }

    NSString *nameFile = [content_Disposition substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(fileNameInit, fileNameLength)];

}
```